# Leaflet.js projection vs Google Maps projection

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, mapbox

I guess that Leaflet has a projection bug. I'm trying to display a image over the Leaflet map using the "ImageOverlay" layer, but it's not fit well such as in Google Maps. We have a Python script that generate temperature graphs using latitude and longitude coordinates as y and x axis. Does anyone know if there is any solution to this trouble?

Leaflet Projection

[image: Leaflet Projection]

Google Maps Projection

[image: Google Maps Projection]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should post this as a Leaflet issue (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues) if you haven't already done so.

Also, it would be great if you could post a JSFiddle or similar with an example of the code you're using to spot any problems.

I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with Leaflet's projection code, but there might well be some issues with the ImageOverlay or how you're using it.